# Accessing the browser's favorites

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I used so far the WebBrowserTask in order to open URLs from code in my WP7 app, but I am interested in accessing the links saved in the browser's favorites. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think there is any API available in Windows Phone SDK to do so

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to access the inbuilt app on WP7 unless there is a task available in the API